# component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose(); not working inside apex controller's returned promise

Tags: lightning-aura-components, modal, lightning-overlaylibrary

I have a parent component with the `<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>` component added.

The parents controller creates an instance of the modal component, assigns it to the body of the modal, and displays the modal using `component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal()`. Nothing used in the footer.

Now, inside the modal component I have two buttons, 'Cancel' and 'Save'. Cancel just closes the modal, while Save makes a callout to the apex controller, *then* closes the modal.

Both button methods utilize `component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();`... however, it only works for the Cancel button.

The Save button fires the `notifyClose` method from the `then()` function of the promise returned by the apex controller, and this seems to cause an error.

**Console Log Error**: `There is no event definition for event "notify", probably because there is no component to handling it.`

```
submitSaveObject : function(component, saveObj){
    var action = component.get('c.saveConfiguration');
    action.setParams({ "saveObj" : JSON.stringify(saveObj)});

    var actionPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){

        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback( function(actionResult){
            var state = actionResult.getState();
            console.log('apex callback result: ');
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                var result = actionResult.getReturnValue();
                resolve(result);        
            } else if (state === "ERROR"){
                reject();
            }

        }));

        $A.enqueueAction(action);       
    });

    actionPromise.then(function(returnValue){
        alert('Save successful!');
        //this is throwing an error
        component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();

    });
}
```

How can I successfully close the modal in such a way that it is enqueued after the asynch call to the apex controller?

Comment: I had this issue before and `notifyClose();` doesn't seem to work anymore, I used `close();`

Comment: Eric when I use `component.find("overlayLib").close();` instead of notifyClose() I get a component error saying close() is not a function.

Comment: Makes sense, this is my entire function that handles "cancel"
handleCancel : function(component, event) { 
        component.get("v.modalPromise").then(
            function (modal) {
                modal.close();
            }
        );
    },

Comment: Interesting, and thanks for the tip... so is `v.modalPromise` assigned the promise returned when you first open the modal using `component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal()`?

Comment: So the problem I'm running into with your solution is my `component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal()` is fired inside the `$A.createComponent()`method where I create the modal's body and also set the parameters to pass to the modal component. To use your method I'd need the promise returned by `showCustomModal` to be passed to the modal cmp as a param, so I can use the promises' `then` function to get the modal obj and use the `close()` method. But how can I pass that promise as a param when it is being generated within `$A.createComponent()`'s callback function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried by adding a callback in .then

```
actionPromise.then($A.getCallback(function(returnValue){
        alert('Save successful!');
        //this is throwing an error
        component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();

    }));
```

Comment: It worked! Such a simple solution too, thanks Manjot! So it appears that I can also just include the `notifyClose` in my initial `getCallback` when I make the callout to Apex... so I suppose this means that `$A.getCallback` has access to the component by default?

Comment: I think it has something to do with modifying lightning component outside framework lifecycle. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm?search_text=$A.getcallback

Answer (score 1):

I am not a javascript wizard, but let me try putting my thought. You are not passing `component` to `actionPromise` method. Thus it doesn't have a component to fire .**notifyClose();**

As `actionPromise` happens asynchronously, somewhere in future, where component may or may not exists . it has no access to `component`

You have to pass it, Something like

```
submitSaveObject : function(component, saveObj){
    var action = component.get('c.saveConfiguration');
    action.setParams({ "saveObj" : JSON.stringify(saveObj)});

    var actionPromise = this.executeAction(component, accAction);

    actionPromise.then(function(returnValue){
        alert('Save successful!');
        //this is throwing an error
        component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();

    });
}


executeAction: function(cmp, action, callback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback( function(actionResult){
            var state = actionResult.getState();
            console.log('apex callback result: ');
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                var result = actionResult.getReturnValue();
                resolve(result);        
            } else if (state === "ERROR"){
                reject();
            }

        }));
    }
}
```

Src: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2016/12/javascript-promises-in-lightning_30.html

Comment: Pranay, I agree with your assessment, but can you explain how your solution is different from my attempt above? Although you are passing the component to your `executeAction` method, you aren't passing it into the Promise inside that method. I believe if you ran your code the `notifyClose()` wouldn't do anything, like with my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for the modal, I did this a few months ago and I may be doing things here that you don't need to do anymore.  My solution may be overly complicated for what you need

Inside my component markup I create my attributes

```
<aura:attribute name="modalPromise" type="Aura.Component" />
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib" />
```

I also create custom components and inject them into the modal but I don't believe you need to do that

```
showModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    var modalBody;
    var modalFooter;

    $A.createComponents([
        ["c:DataTableNoteModalContent", {
            label:"modalContent",
            "textAreaInputValue" : component.getReference("v.textAreaInputValue")
        }],
        ["c:DataTableNoteModalFooter", {
            label:"modalFooter", 
            "rowID" : component.get("v.rowID"),
            "dataTableID" : component.get("v.dataTableID"),
            "buttonClickEvent":component.getReference("c.onButtonClick")
        }]],
        function(components, status) {
            if(status === "SUCCESS") {
                modalBody = components[0];
                modalFooter = components[1];
                var modalPromise = component.find("overlayLib").showCustomModal({
                    header: "Add",
                    body: modalBody, 
                    footer : modalFooter,
                    showCloseButton: true,
                    cssClass: "",
                    closeCallback: function(){
                        component.set("v.textAreaInputValue", component.get("v.textAreaInputPreviousValue"));
                    }
                });
                component.set("v.modalPromise", modalPromise);
            }
        }
    );
},
```

I have my button in my footer

```
<aura:attribute name="modalFooter" type="Aura.Component[]" >
<lightning:button aura:id="cancel" name="cancel" iconName="action:remove" 
 label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}" class="slds-button_neutral" />
</aura:attribute>
```

Then that calls my helper function

```
handleCancel : function(component, event) { 
    component.get("v.modalPromise").then(
        function (modal) {
            modal.close();
        }
    );
},
```

I hesitate to just code dump on you but I hope this can help

Comment: This is actually super helpful, but something seems strange: in your parent cmp you set `modalPromise` as an attribute for the parent cmp... But you then reference `modalPromise` in your modal cmp. I would have thought the modal's controller couldn't access the parent's attribute without it being specifically passed as a parameter! But I'll give it a try and see what happens...

Comment: Sure enough, I get an error when attempting to call `component.get("v.modalPromise").then()` from within the modal cmp, since `modalPromise` isn't a defined attribute in the modal cmp, just the parent cmp.